# Remove subprocess buffer while reading a file

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I need to monitor a file in real time and extract certain information to inform users about the progress. Basically something similar to "tail -f" which outputs right away the lines added to the file. The problem is that it seems I have a buffering issues which delays getting the latest lines.

Here is my code:

```
f = subprocess.Popen(['tail','-F','/myfile'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
while True:
    line = f.stdout.readline()
    print (line)
```

I've also tried "sys.stdout.write" and "sys.stdout.flush" but that made no difference. I've tried to execute the Python script with "-u" but it changed nothing.

Could you please help?

Comment: Try buffsize parameter = 0 https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Comment: A better approach (instead of tail) could be select library instead : https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html

Comment: unfortunately, the buffer is still active.

Comment: @JBernardo Could you show some code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right way, but using the wrong stream. Calling `flush` is the right idea. But `sys.std*` are the streams of your script, not the streams in the `Popen` object.

Use `f.stdout.reconfigure(line_buffering=True)`. That sets the stream inside the `Popen` object to use `flush` automatically.

Instead of using `tail`, you could also just read from the file:

```
with open('/myfile', buffering=1) as f:
    for line in f:  # reads the file line-by line
        print(line)
```